# How to use ssh from shell script without waiting for password?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, script

I can not use public key method. I also don't want to use expect script. I searched this site for solution but everybody is talking about these solutions.

Is there any other way like command line parameter to ssh command (e.g. --password='asdf') or input redirection ("<") ?

Comment: I think SSH client has been engineered to prevent what you want to do. But I'm not fully sure.

Comment: You might get better answers if you asked this question on serverfault.com

Comment: @Nicolas please let me know that option, I am not able to find it in man page of openssh client.    
@chakrit I thought this as scripting question thats why I asked it here.

Comment: You might also have a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459182/using-expect-to-pass-a-password-to-ssh
last answer.

Comment: @Nicolas The answer mention use of another client like putty, but I want to use openssh client.

Comment: as far as I am aware there is no other method as public keys to get automatic login. you can try to hackup your own ssh client that would pass a hardcoded password but that won't be secure .....

Comment: As for *"I can not use public key method"* -- I assume you know how to use that, but still cannot use it for whatever reason? Or do you *think* you cannot use it?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you just don't wan to write an expect script, or whether you don't want to use anything that uses expect?

Answer (score 2):

I would have say to use RSA key or try this one: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/ **bare in mind that you need to install `expect` tool**.

But since you have say **NO** to RSA and to `expect`, the only way is to write your own script utilizing Twisted's `conch` (http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/conch/documentation/examples/) or any other platform available which offer SSH implementation such as ruby or Perl

Comment: I dont want expect script. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: answer revised ;~)

Answer (score 2):

You could try host-based authentication to log in *without* a password. In this case you don't need a private key for the user. But you still need a host key. Would this be a possible solution for you?

The man page of ssh sais:

> Host-based authentication works as follows: If the machine the user logs
>        in from is listed in /etc/hosts.equiv or /etc/ssh/shosts.equiv on the
>        remote machine, and the user names are the same on both sides, or if the
>        files ~/.rhosts or ~/.shosts exist in the user's home directory on the
>        remote machine and contain a line containing the name of the client
>        machine and the name of the user on that machine, the user is considered
>        for login.  Additionally, the server must be able to verify the client's
>        host key (see the description of /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts and
>        ~/.ssh/known_hosts, below) for login to be permitted.  This authentication method closes security holes due to IP spoofing, DNS spoofing, and
>        routing spoofing.  [Note to the administrator: /etc/hosts.equiv,
>        ~/.rhosts, and the rlogin/rsh protocol in general, are inherently insecure and should be disabled if security is desired.]

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with Python, you can try [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use The dropbear SSH client, which allows specifying the password on the command line, like this: [Dropbear for automatic login for shell scripts](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Telnet/SSH_and_the_Command_Line#Automatic_Login_.28for_shell_scripts.29)

Answer (score 1):

In debian and derivatives, there's a package called sshpass ([website here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/)) that's designed to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `ControlMaster` option in ssh_config. This allows you to open a authenticated tunnel by hand that all following ssh connections uses.

Answer (score -1):

If you have X running, you can write a tiny X code (e.g. in Tcl/Tk or Tkinter) that sends the password to stdout. Then all you have to do is set the environment variable SSH_ASKPASS to the path of that code.

from man ssh:

> SSH_ASKPASS           If ssh needs a passphrase, it will read the
>   passphrase from the current terminal if it was run
>                              from a terminal.  If ssh does not have a terminal associated with it but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS
>                              are set, it will execute the program specified by SSH_ASKPASS and open an X11 window to read the
>                              passphrase.  This is particularly useful when calling ssh from a .xsession or related script.
>                              (Note that on some machines it may be necessary to redirect the input from /dev/null to make
>                              this work.)